# Dropzone.js is unable to grab the value from the HTML Editor CKEDITOR

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

Working on a form that will allow users to drop files in for my new help desk ticket module.  The problem I'm having is that when I submit the form, the text area field (which is using the html editor CKEDITOR) is coming up empty in the database.  I've tried several different options to get the data from CKEDITOR but none of them have worked with dropzone.  Hoping maybe somebody knows how to get around this, if not I might just have to look at another option for a drag and drop uploader.

This is the code in question that I've been having problems with.

formData.append("description", jQuery("textarea#description").val());

I've also tried

var html = CKEDITOR.instances.description.getData();

```
  Dropzone.options.myDropzone= {
  url: 'upload.php',
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  uploadMultiple: true,
  parallelUploads: 5,
  maxFiles: 5,
  maxFilesize: 1,           
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  init: function() {
     dzClosure = this;



 document.getElementById("submit-all").addEventListener("click", function(e) {                      
 e.preventDefault();
 e.stopPropagation();
 dzClosure.processQueue();
 });

 //send all the form data along with the files:
 this.on("sendingmultiple", function(data, xhr, formData) {

 formData.append("department", jQuery("#department").val());
 formData.append("category", jQuery("#category").val());
 formData.append("subject", jQuery("#subject").val());     

 formData.append("description", jQuery("textarea#description").val());


 });

 }
```

}

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it seems like dropzone sends `text` attribute while ckeditor changes `value`. Try this before processing queue, it works for me:

```
 $("textarea#description").text($("textarea#description").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CKEDITOR.instances['description'].getData()`, you will get ckeditor's data. `['description']` is the ID which is used for calling ckeditor. I have faced same problem & have solved it using it.